# *ngIf with generic string expression that evaluates bool

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

Hi I am trying to writing *ngIf statement which takes generic string as a input which will in-turn return true/false
e.g.

below is sample component html and ts file.

```
   <div>
      <p *ngIf='hideExpression'>
        This will be visible only if employee member is employee.
      </p>
   </div>
```

**users.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  hideExpression = '';
  isEmployee = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Note:  I am going to fetch this expression from Database which is stored in string form
    this.hideExpression = 'isEmployee === true';
  }
}
```

My member variable, `hideExpression` holds a valid string expression which will return either true or false.  How can I use this `hideExperssion` as a parameter to `*ngIf`

Comment: You can't. Don't put code in strings. Put code in functions. Just make hideExpression a functionor a method.

Comment: eval() function can you help you might be.

Comment: @PareshGami, excellent.  Its working as expected but looks like typescript is not happy with it.  TypeScript has built-in rule named 'no-eval'.  We can ignore and move forward but there has to be a better way to address this.

Comment: You can ignore rules // tslint:disable-next-line:no-eval :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put expressions in strings use a Method for that

```
<div>
      <p *ngIf='isEmployee'>
        This will be visible only if employee member is employee.
      </p>
   </div>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {


  isEmployee = false;
  constructor() { }
       hideExpression();
  ngOnInit() {

  }
   private hideExpression(){
     return !this.isEmployee;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I want to implement generic framework and I am planning to fetch hideExpression from Database.  I have updated my original question.

Answer (score -1):

Change to `this.hideExpression = this.isEmployee === true;`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hideExpression = this.isEmployee === true;
}
```

Update

If you want to fetch hideExpression from Database, you need create a service and fetch data from DB like this

```
constructor(private yourService: EmployeeService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.yourService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(data=>{
            this.hideExpression = data.isEmployee === true;
    });
}

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    }

    getEmployee(id){
        return this.http.get(`/api/employee?id=${id}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only evaluate the expression once, when the component is being initialized.

Comment: Idea is, I want to implement generic framework and I am planning to fetch hideExpression from Database.